# Recover deleted and possibly overwritten partition using Testdisk -- best practice?

Tags: data-recovery, partition-recovery, testdisk

Before [using Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) to recover a partition, does it make sense to clone the damaged partition in question to another drive (or the whole HDD for that matter), and try recovery on the clone -- or is that nonsense because the structure on the clone is never the same as the one on the damaged drive?

Answer (score 1):

The word "clone" suggests the generation of an exact duplicate.
So the sentence

> or is that nonsense because the structure on the clone is never the same as the one on the damaged drive?
> is wrong.

If the drive has any kind of hardware dammage ( for instance unreadable setors) or if you intend to use write-functions within Testdisk (for instance partition table writing or MFT repair) I strongly recommend duplicating the drive to another one with the same sector characteristics like 512e/4096.  (e=emulated)

Just copying a partition leaves out some drive meta data information.

It appears that your question in different wording has already been answered here:

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=11720

What a surprise. :)